# PL SQL Procedure error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, parameters, procedure

I am creating this procedure to retrieve information from a database. This is my first creating a procedure as well. I keep getting an error around the parameters that I am trying to set when I create the procedure. It says something along the lines of expecting a different symbol where the semi-colon is. **Now I am getting an error around my SQL statement, inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HIREDATE
(
D_ID IN EMP.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE; 
H_YEAR IN EMP.HIRE_DATE%TYPE;
)
--
AS
--
v_Last              VARCHAR2(20);               
v_First             VARCHAR2(25);
v_HireDate          DATE;
--
BEGIN
--
SELECT LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,HIRE_DATE 
INTO v_Last,v_First,v_HireDate
FROM EMP WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = D_ID
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIRE_DATE) = H_YEAR;
--
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE(v_Last||','||v_First||'      '||v_HireDate);
--
EXCEPTION
--
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE('No data found for Department '||D_ID);
--
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE('An unexpected error has occurred!');
--
END;
```

Comment: You don't put semi-colons in parameter definitions.  Commas.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters should be separated by commas (,). You have semi-colons.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HIREDATE(
 D_ID IN EMP.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE,
 H_YEAR IN EMP.HIRE_DATE%TYPE) AS ...
```